# JSON in SharePoint Online - Property height is not allowed

Tags: json, sharepoint-online

My code below works but I was hoping to add in

```
"height": "50px"
```

instead of the line ...

```
"class": "ms-bgColor-red"
```

But JSON complains with "Property height is not allowed"

```
 {
    "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
    "hideSelection": true,
    "hideColumnHeader": true,
    "rowFormatter": {
      "elmType": "div",
      "attributes": {
        "class": "sp-row-card"
      },
      "children": [
        {
          "elmType": "div",
          "style": {
            "text-align": "left"
          },
          "children": [
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "attributes": {
                  "class": "ms-bgColor-red"
              },
              "txtContent": "[$MyVal]"
            },
            {
              "elmType": "div",
              "attributes": {
                "class": "ms-bgColor-red"
              },
              "txtContent": "[$MyVal]"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Please use the below JSON formatting:**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/row-formatting.schema.json",
  "hideSelection": true,
  "hideColumnHeader": true,
  "rowFormatter": {
    "elmType": "div",
    "attributes": {
      "class": "sp-row-card"
    },
    "children": [
      {
        "elmType": "div",
        "style": {
          "text-align": "left"
        },
        "children": [
          {
            "elmType": "div",
            "attributes": {
              "class": "ms-bgColor-red"
            },
            "txtContent": "[$Title]"
          },
          { 
            "elmType": "div", 
            "style": {
              "height": "50px"
             },
            "txtContent": "[$VHE]" 
          }
        ] 
      } 
    ] 
  } 
}
```

[image]